# Индексация List<int[]> с единицы

Tags: java, массивы, список, index

Доброго времени суток.

*Имеется список массивов с индексацией, начинающейся с ноля. Мне же необходимо, чтобы и в списке, и в его массивах индексация начиналась с 1. Каким простым способом это можно реализовать?*

Каждый следующий массив, находящийся в списке создается путем клонирования одного из предыдущих.

**Класс в программе обязательно должен быть только один - главный, такова специфика поставленной задачи.**

Могу ли я в список первым элементом (т.е. с индексом 0) заранее до ввода массивов положить `null` , чтобы индексация не пустых массивов началась уже с единицы?

```
public class Main implements Cloneable {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    List<int[]> a = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 

int n;
    for( ; ; ) {
        n = reader.nextInt(); 
        if(n<100000) break;            
    }      
int[] a0 = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a0[i] = reader.nextInt();
    a.add(a0);
int m;
    for( ; ; ) {
        m = reader.nextInt(); 
        if(m<100000) break;            
    } 

         String[] request = new String[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
         request[i] = reader.next();


    if ( request[i].equals("create"))  {

            int version = reader.nextInt();
            int position = reader.nextInt(); 
            int symbol = reader.nextInt();

          create(a, position, version, symbol);

    } else
    if (request[i].equals("get"))     {

            int version = reader.nextInt();
            int position = reader.nextInt();

             System.out.println(get( a, position, version));

    }  
        }      

    }

   public static void create(List<int[]> a, int position, int version, int symbol){

          a.add((a.get(version)).clone());
          int last=a.size()-1;
          a.get(last)[position]=symbol;

      }


    public static int get(List<int[]> a, int position, int version){

          return a.get(version)[position];
          }

   }
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом List.add(index, element); в нем вы можете указать индекс элемента добавите как вариант поле int counter = 1; а на месте используйте  List.add(counter++, (a.get(version)).clone())...к слову с получением можно поступить так же. ) Удачи

Comment: можете, конечно. но это будет неправильно. просто отнимайте единицу, когда это нужно.

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения инкапсуляции совершенно неважно, как именно ваши методы будут внутри себя получать данные из массива и что с ними делать, важен только интерфейс, который "торчит" наружу. Поэтому если есть необходимость для "внешних пользователей" представить нумерацию начинающейся с единицы, наиболее корректным будет отнимать единицу внутри соответствующих методов (в которые передается индекс).
Если вы запишете null первым элементом, то у вас будет нестыковка: кол-во элементов коллекций обычно равно `size()-1`, а у вас первый будет null, и кол-во значащих элементов будет `size()-2`, код будет путаный и непонятный. А никакого выигрыша при этом не видно.